# Tox failing when run inside Github Actions because pytest uses incorrect python version to run tests

Tags: python, python-3.x, github-actions, tox, coverage.py

- I have a basic Python project ([Full repository HERE](https://github.com/slidenerd/gha-fail-test/tree/wip/github-actions)) with a tox.ini file which runs on 3.10. When run locally, all tests pass and coverage is at 100%
- When run on Github actions, the coverage is only 92% because it uses Python 3.8 for some reason to run the tests inside CI

**tox.ini**

```
[tox]
isolated_build = true
envlist = py310
skipsdist = true
[flake8]
extend-exclude = .venv
extend-ignore = E731, E203, E501, W503, W605
max-complexity = 10
max-line-length = 88
extend-select = B9
docstring-convention = google
docstring_style = google

[testenv]
whitelist_externals = poetry
commands =
        poetry install -v
        poetry run pytest --typeguard-packages=news --xdoctest --cov -vv
        poetry run flake8 --verbose
        poetry run black src tests --verbose
        poetry run isort . --verbose
        poetry run bandit src --recursive --verbose
        poetry run mypy src --verbose
        poetry run darglint src --verbosity=2
        poetry run darglint tests --verbosity=2

passenv = SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```

**tests.yml Github Actions file**

```
name: Run tests
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
      - test/github-actions
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
      - test/github-actions
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      fail-fast: false
      matrix:
        python-version: ["3.10"]
    steps:
      - name: Checkout the repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install poetry
        run: |
          curl -O -sSL https://install.python-poetry.org/install-poetry.py
          python install-poetry.py -y --version 1.1.14
          echo "PATH=${HOME}/.poetry/bin:${PATH}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
          rm install-poetry.py
      - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
        uses: actions/setup-python@v4
        with:
          python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
          cache: 'poetry'
      - name: Install dependencies
        
        run: |
          poetry env use ${{ matrix.python-version }}
          poetry install --no-interaction
      - name: Run pytest with coverage, xdoctest and typeguard
        run: poetry run tox
```

The output from GitHub Actions after running tox looks like this

```
Run poetry run tox
py310 create: /home/runner/work/news/news/.tox/py310
py310 run-test-pre: PYTHONHASHSEED='586544516'
py310 run-test: commands[0] | poetry install -v
Using virtualenv: /home/runner/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/news-Rk7gf-lU-py3.10
Installing dependencies from lock file
Finding the necessary packages for the current system
Package operations: 0 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals, 65 skipped
  • Removing atomicwrites (1.4.1): Skipped for the following reason: Not currently installed
  • Installing pyparsing (3.0.9): Skipped for the following reason: Already installed
  ...
Installing the current project: news (0.1.0)
py310 run-test: commands[1] | poetry run pytest --typeguard-packages=news --xdoctest --cov -vv
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.8.10, pytest-7.1.2, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /home/runner/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs/news-Rk7gf-lU-py3.10/bin/python
cachedir: .tox/py310/.pytest_cache
rootdir: /home/runner/work/news/news
plugins: sugar-0.9.5, clarity-1.0.1, typeguard-2.13.3, cov-3.0.0, xdoctest-1.0.1
collecting ... collected 4 items
src/news/main.py::main:0 PASSED                                          [ 25%]
tests/test_main.py::test_main PASSED                                     [ 50%]
tests/test_main.py::test_typeguard PASSED                                [ 75%]
tests/test_news.py::test_version PASSED                                  [100%]
---------- coverage: platform linux, python 3.8.10-final-0 -----------
Name                   Stmts   Miss Branch BrPart  Cover
--------------------------------------------------------
src/news/__init__.py       1      0      0      0   100%
src/news/main.py          10      1      2      0    92%
--------------------------------------------------------
TOTAL                     11      1      2      0    92%
FAIL Required test coverage of 100.0% not reached. Total coverage: 92.31%
============================== 4 passed in 0.06s ===============================
ERROR: InvocationError for command /home/runner/.local/bin/poetry run pytest --typeguard-packages=news --xdoctest --cov -vv (exited with code 1)
___________________________________ summary ____________________________________
ERROR:   py310: commands failed
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The tests are being run using Python 3.8 for some reason. When I run tox locally it works perfectly as it runs them on Python 3.10. Any ideas how to fix this issue and what is causing it?

Comment: Is your project public? If so, could you share the link to the github page?

Comment: @JürgenGmach here you go https://github.com/slidenerd/gha-fail-test/tree/wip/github-actions the branch called wip/github-actions has all the gha flows

Comment: Thanks - currently I do not have time to investigate, but from a quick look: in gha you drive tox via poetry, and in tox.ini you drive poetry via tox. So it is poetry -> tox > poetry. Apart from I do not have experience with poetry, this seems really odd. I would suggest that you run tox directly in gha: tox -> poetry.